# Is there a way to run heroku redis-cli with options, like --bigkeys?

Tags: heroku, redis

I can run `heroku redis:cli -a myapp -c myapp`, and it works fine.

But when I run `heroku redis:cli --bigkeys -a myapp -c myapp`, it yields `no redis instance found`

Answer (score 5):

I discovered I can use local redis-cli with -u:

```
redis-cli -u `heroku config:get REDIS_URL -a myapp` --bigkeys
```